# Multi-class cross validation LIBSVM in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, machine-learning, svm, libsvm, cross-validation

I am doing a multi-class SVM to solve a problem. I have 4 classes (1,2,3,4). I am also trying to implement the grid search method to find the best values of C and gamma. The code I adapted was from the official FAQ LIBSVM page: http://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/libsvm/faq.html#f803

The code there is about a single class problem. I tried to optimize it to fit my case. I followed their suggestion which they wrote here: http://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/libsvm/faq.html#f507

I tried to find the best possible parameters (C and gamma) for each pair of two classes (one-against-all method). My code is as follows:

```
%# Find best values for c and g using cross validation
bestcv                  = 0;
for k=1:numLabels
bestcv(k)                  = 0;

for log2c = -3:3,
for log2g = -5:4,
cmd                 = ['-v 10 -c ', num2str(2^log2c), ' -g ', num2str(2^log2g)];

cv                  = svmtrain(double(gridLabel==k), gridData, cmd);
if (cv >= bestcv(k)),
  bestcv(k)            = cv; 
  bestc(k)             = 2^log2c; 
  bestg(k)             = 2^log2g;
end


fprintf('%g %g %g (best c=%g, g=%g, rate=%g)\n', log2c, log2g, cv, bestc, bestg, bestcv);
end
end
end
```

Then, after finding the optimal parameters, I train the data with different parameters for every pair of classes (one against all) as in the following code:

```
model                   = cell(numLabels,1);
for k=1:numLabels
model{k}                = svmtrain(double(trainLabel==k), trainData, ['-c ', num2str(bestc(k)),' -g ', num2str(bestg(k)), ' -b 1']);
end
```

My questions are:

- Is this the right way to do cross validation with multiple classes?
- How can I measure the over all performance of my model after having different cross validation values? If by plotting the cost function, how to do that in my case?
- How can I optimize the grid search method to fit it for my problem?

I am looking forward to reading your comments.